# Consulta SQL utilizando order by filtrando pelo resgistros

Tags: sql, select, firebird, sql-select, order-by

Tenho a tabela:

```
| cod | hora  | produto | Amostra | Min | Max |
|-----|-------|---------|---------|-----|-----|
|   1 | 08:00 |  96722  |   1     | 100 | 200 |
|   2 | 08:23 |  96721  |   1     | 90  | 90  |
|   3 | 08:50 |  96722  |   2     | 100 | 100 |
|   4 | 09:50 |  96722  |   2     | 100 | 200 |
|   5 | 08:30 |  96721  |   2     | 90  | 90  |
|   6 | 08:28 |  96721  |   1     | 12  | 25  |
```

Quero que me liste assim:

```
| cod | hora  | produto | Amostra | Min | Max |
|-----|-------|---------|---------|-----|-----|
|   2 | 08:23 |  96721  |   1     | 90  | 90  |
|   5 | 08:30 |  96721  |   2     | 90  | 90  |
|   6 | 08:28 |  96721  |   1     | 12  | 25  |
|   1 | 08:00 |  96722  |   1     | 100 | 200 |
|   4 | 09:50 |  96722  |   2     | 100 | 200 |
|   3 | 08:50 |  96722  |   2     | 100 | 100 |
```

Estou tentado fazer dessa forma:

```
select * from tb_tabela
order by
tb_tabela.produto,
tb_tabela.amostra,
tb_tabela.hora
```

Ele está me retornando errado, conforme a baixo:

```
| cod | hora  | produto | Amostra | Min | Max |
|-----|-------|---------|---------|-----|-----|
|   2 | 08:23 |  96721  |   1     | 90  | 90  |
|   6 | 08:28 |  96721  |   1     | 12  | 25  | //errado
|   5 | 08:30 |  96721  |   2     | 90  | 90  |
|   1 | 08:00 |  96722  |   1     | 100 | 200 |
|   3 | 08:50 |  96722  |   2     | 100 | 100 | //errado
|   4 | 09:50 |  96722  |   2     | 100 | 200 |
```

Comment: Olá Tiago, eu não sou especialista em SQL nem nada mas da forma que você quer acho que não tem como fazer... Como executar um order by pra vir 1, 2 ,1 na coluna Amostra? Não tem outra coluna pra ordenar? Tipo usando a Min/Max?

Comment: Não da pra usar o Min/Max pois eles podem variar.

Comment: Qual sentido teria em ordenar dessa forma? em seu exemplo nenhum dos campos tem um conjunto de ordem valido para ser feito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

testa essa query

```
select * from tb_tabela
order by
tb_tabela.produto ASC,
tb_tabela.Max DESC,
tb_tabela.Min DESC
```

deve funcionar ( editado )

Comment: não funcionou, deu o mesmo problema

Comment: editei a query testa agora

Comment: Funcionou? Eu havia esquecido de inserir o max na query inicial

Comment: funcionou, valeu

Comment: de boa ^^ da pelo menos um up ai rsss